# Outlook Web Hosted Address Book?

Tags: outlook, synchronization, remote-access, addressbook, contact-list

Is it possible for outlook (and mac mail / other email software) to identify a remotely hosted address book?

For example if I had an address database hosted on a website. Could I publish a csv or specific address book format that outlook / mail etc connects to or automatically syncs with?

Comment: 5 years later and still no solution to this. It's a shame...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an address book provider (Extended MAPI, C++ or Delphi only) for the regular Windows version of Outlook, but you cannot do that for OWA or the Mac version of Outlook. The best you can do is copy your contacts to the Contacts folder.